# UISegmentedControl CoreData Binding Error

Tags: ios, core-data

I keep getting this error when i try to bind a nsobject to a segment control

```
UserLocation isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7477a60
2013-01-22 12:44:58.115 Momentum[39936:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UserLocation isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7477a60'
```

I have verified that my core data object has data.

```
NSarray *arrayuserlocation = [[MMIStore defaultStore] loadAllUserLocation];
UISegmentedControl *segControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:arrayuserlocation];
[segControl addTarget:self action:@selector(didChangeSegmentControl:)      forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[segControl setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
[segControl setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
```

EDIT

To the answer the question below

```
- (NSMutableArray *)loadAllUserLocation
{
    if (!allItems) {NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *e = [[model entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"UserLocation"];
            [request setEntity:e]
    NSError *error;
        NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
        if (!result) {
            [NSException raise:@"Fetch failed"
                        format:@"Reason: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
        }

        allItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:result];
}
 return allItems;
```

It returns an array

I was able to solve my problem by doing the following.

```
 NSArray *arraylocation = [[MMIStore defaultStore] loadAllUserLocation];
    NSMutableArray *newarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (UserLocation *user in arraylocation)
    {

        NSLog(@"%@ found", user.locationNm);
        [newarray addObject:user.locationNm];

    }
```

And using newarray as the datasource for the segment control.

Comment: `NSarray arrayuserlocation` should be `NSarray *arrayuserlocation`, right? And what is inside `loadAllUserLocation`? It seems like it is not an NSString. That is why it is crashing.

Comment: There is an int property in userlocation.  Is that the problem?

Comment: As per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/initWithItems:) your items array should be _"an array of NSString objects (for segment titles) or UIImage objects (for segment images)."_ So can you please add the complete `loadAllUserLocation` method showing its return type?

Comment: Can you please tell which param of `userlocation` do you want to display as `UISegmentedControl` titles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, the issue is that you are passing `userlocation` objects instead of `NSString` or `UIImage` objects required.

As per the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UISegmentedControl/initWithItems%3a) your items array should be "an array of NSString objects (for segment titles) or UIImage objects (for segment images)."

You need to fetch the strings from user location as,

```
NSarray *arrayuserlocation = [[[MMIStore defaultStore] loadAllUserLocation] valueForKey:@"locationNm"];//use the param name here
```

This should give you an array of all strings from the array of objects.

Comment: Hello,  Thank you very much for your insight.  Should i delete this question?

Comment: @KevinKohler, Thanks for accepting. You dont have to do all those mentioned in your edit. Just use the above line. It should work.

Comment: You dont have to delete it. It is not a bad question after your edit and should help others who are facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the `arrayuserlocation` array should contain `NSString`s instead of `NSManagedObjects`.

Answer (score 0):

The code that's throwing the exception is expecting you to pass it an `NSString` (this is the object that responds to `isEqualToString:`).  However, you are passing it a `UserLocation` object.  You need to load up `arrayuserlocation` with strings from the `UserLocation` object, not just send an array of objects themselves.

Comment: Ah, How would i do that?  it has an int and string property? :)